# System design: how to support sorting a large number of records by a fairly arbitrary function

Tags: sorting, database-design, architecture, nosql

Suppose, you’re asked to build a system where you’ll have a large number of records (billions?) with millions more added every day. These records have properties like *w,v,x,y,z*. You want to design an application that is centered around a view of these records sorted by some function, ***F***, that takes in *x,y*, and some values, *a,b* that are not part of the records, and are *NOT known at insertion time*. The ordering doesn’t have to be 100% strict, but for every pair of records in the view **R**<sub>i</sub> and **R**<sub>i-1</sub> in the view ***F***(x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>,a,b) > ***F***(x<sub>i-1</sub>,y<sub>i-1</sub>,a,b) with high probability.

For example, if you wanted to add a “Nearby” view to Instagram (which has a bunch of photos), which would display a list of photos sorted by some function of proximity to user and freshness of the photo (e.g. how recently it was posted).
So in this example *x* and *y* are photo location and creation timestamp; *a* and *b* are the user’s location and current timestamp.

How would you design such a system? What questions would you ask? Are there some combination of data stores out there that are good for this sort of thing?

How does the design change if you want the view to update in close to real time as new records are added?
Any papers or articles out there that have investigated similar problems?

NOTE: I don’t actually work at Instagram or do anything related to this problem really. Just trying to satisfy a curiosity.

Comment: Have you done any research/prototyping with Neo4j?

Comment: No, but just from some quick googling, it seems like it's good for doing graph searches. I may be dense, but how do you model the problem above as a graph?

Answer (score 1):

I've added an answer because I couldn't fit this in the comments area. Firstly I would not use an RDMS for this. I would use a graph database like Neo4j. When modelling a system using a graph database, it is typical that you begin with a fresh piece of paper and ask yourself what questions should be database answer. What that thinking process provides are the entities that are inherent in your domain. It is the entities which will be represented as nodes in your graph.

Once you have the entities and their associated properties (akin to columns in RDMS type systems), you then set out to define relationships between the entities. In typical RDMS type systems the typical relationships that are specified are those concerning referential integrity (boring, yawn, yawn, yawn). What a graph database allows you do is to specify associations/relationships which are more than that. In your Nearby example, for each association I can specify the proximity value between a user and a photo. You can then use the Cypher language to query all the nodes which satisfy some proximity predicate.

Finally, in terms of scalability, Neo4j scales to billions of nodes.

Comment: But you only know the location of the user at query time, not at node insertion time. I guess you could approximate this by decreasing the precision of the user's location to a postal code or something and having postal code nodes in your graph connected by edges with distance as weights.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you are trying to build now. Your question was a bit abstract. So you want to basically bring up a list of photos based on the *current* location of a user? If so, you would already have nodes to represent those entities in your graph database i.e. user node, user_location node. As you do real-time updates on the user location, you will have to do real-time updates to your relationships between nodes; I've never done this type of processing before so please check with the Neo4j people if this easy and fast to do. Then it's a simple matter of re-running your query.